# sending sms with php via email or direct no

Tags: php

how can i send sms message to a phone number so that it forwards the sms to the number sent by me........via php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

**[Sending SMS with PHP](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/sms/)**